Is there an MSVC equivalent to gcc's __attribute__(returns_nonnull))?
I learned about this little feature of GCC/Clang today:
Something * MyFunctionThatNeverReturnsNULL() __attribute__((returns_nonnull))
{
   // code here that will never return a NULL value
   static Something blah;
   return &blah;
}

[...]

int main()
{
   Something * s = MyFunctionThatNeverReturnsNULL();
   if (s) // useful:  compiler generates a warning here since this test will always return true!
   {
      // do something
   }
   else
   {
      // do something else
   }
}

This feature is useful because if I have calling code that is erroneously expecting a NULL return value to indicate failure, the __attribute__((returns_nonnull)) annotation allows the compiler to print a warning so that I can know to look at that code and fix it.
My question is, does MSVC have anything similar/equivalent so that the same type of warnings might be generated when compiling under Windows?

_Nonnull or _Notnull_ in MSVC I think. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6504?view=msvc-170

@Brandon that seems to be for function-arguments; will it also work for return-values ?

Conventionally in C++ that function would return a reference instead and then there is no way that it could ever not refer to an object. In C the attribute would be useful though.

Personally I feel the standard has a better way of expressing that you get a non null pointer, its called a reference.  Something * MyFunctionThatNeverReturnsNULL() can become Something& MyFunctionThatNeverReturnsNULL() and now there is no reason to ever check that the return type is null since you are guaranteed to refer to an object (as long as a dangling reference wasn't returned, but that is UB land).

@NathanOliver in general I agree with you, and that's usually what I do, but in this case the function has to return a pointer because reasons.

If not Brandon's comment, perhaps something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26429?view=msvc-170

MSVC has __assume keyword, I don't know if compiler would catch code that ignores assumption. You can also return not_null<Something*> template instead of raw pointer (https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/b39e7e4b0987859f5b19ff7686b149c916588658/include/gsl/pointers#L96)

_Ret_notnull_ is one of the standard SAL Annotations you can use.
An example on the forward declaration:
#include <sal.h>

Ret_notnull_ Something* MyFunctionThatNeverReturnsNULL();

As for how you enable the compiler or the prefast tools to detect these sorts of errors.... let me get back my desk to check for a valid example. I'll update this answer later.

Hmm, I can get the Ret_notnull_ keyword to compile (in VS 2022) but it doesn't seem to want to actually emit a warning when the calling code checks the never-NULL return-value for NULL.  I wonder if the keyword is implemented to check only the implementation of the function that it is decorating?

@JeremyFriesner - start here: https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/codeanalysis/  These tools have been rebranded over the years, but they basically use the SAL annotations as hint when scanning sources and analyzing binaries.  On my team, we've used it as part of the check-in flow.  All files in a PR get scanned.

@JeremyFriesner - even better : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-overview?view=msvc-170  It looks like you can add /analyze to the cl command line.

yes, I added /analyze to the cl command line; doing so produced warnings for other code-analysis issues, but not for this one.
